# A problem involving monkey and pulley system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

Let there be a monkey of 4 kg and a block of mass 4 kg on the other side.
Since both the masses are same this situation becomes kind of difficult to comprehend. It is known that the monkey's acceleration with respect to rope is 2 m/s^2 and monkey has to climb 10 m up the rope to where the pulley is situated . What i am not getting is what will actually be happening here and how will the monkey actually climb up the rope as the masses on both side are same and accelerate while doing so as well. Primarily,  how will the system behave when monkey applies a force greater than his weight in the form of pulling the rope down and how would the tension developed make the block move as i don't think monkey can climb up without disturbing the block kept on the fixed surface. It would be highly appreciated if someone gives a clear account of the physical events associated with this setup.

Comment: Assume a spherical monkey. (Ha ha!, But seriously...) Assume there is no limit to how fast the monkey can climb. The monkey climbs by pulling downward on the rope—by creating tension in the rope. If the tension is greater than the monkey's weight, then the net force on the monkey is upward, toward the pulley, and the monkey _must_ accelerate in that direction. Meanwhile, the mass M, which weighs the same as the monkey experiences the same tension because it is attached to the same rope. Same mass, same net, upward force... Can you figure out the rest from there?

Comment: Same mass and same upward force ..... wouldn't it imply that they should both have accelration upward , but how would that be possible as it will lead to rope becoming slack(if monkey keeps holding to the same part of rope , which now i think should not be the case) . Also when the monkey slides up the rope while the mass also comes up the equations don't give the answer which is in the book. I think i am missing something

Comment: The monkey cannot accelerate with respect to the rope (as required by the problem statement) by simply "holding to the same part of rope." It has to climb.